# Using replaceRows creates a broken "Copy of"

Tags: google-api, google-fusion-tables

I've run into an interesting behaviour of Fusion Tables. I use replaceRows to update my table, Foo, with data from a CSV file -- that part works fine. However, when finished, this operation seems to leave a new Fusion Table in my Drive, called "Copy of Foo". However, if I try to actually open the table, I get a "Sorry, the table you have requested does not exist" screen instead. The 'copy' table can be moved around and deleted like a regular Drive file. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or is it a bug in Fusion Tables?

For reference, I'm using the Node Google APIs client library to make my requests.